# What does this return code mean? IGYPS0009-E

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I'm writing a COBOL code and cannot figure out why this error code which reads

> "OPEN" should not begin in area "A". It was processed as if found in area "B"

Specifically it is referring to the line under `PROCEDURE DIVISION` of `OPEN INPUT CUST-PROF`

```
      *-----------------------
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
      *-----------------------
       PROGRAM-ID.    FSOC050
      *--------------------
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
      *--------------------
       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
      *
       FILE-CONTROL.
           SELECT CUST-PROF  ASSIGN TO CUSTPROF
                  ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL.
      *-------------
       DATA DIVISION.
      *-------------
       FILE SECTION.
       FD  CUST-PROF RECORDING MODE F.
       01  CUST-PROF-01.
           05  CUST-NO             PIC X(6).
           05  CUST-NAME           PIC X(35).
           05  CUST-STREET-ADDR    PIC X(25).
           05  CUST-CITY           PIC X(11).
           05  CUST-STATE          PIC X(2).
           05  CUST-CARD-TYPE      PIC X(4).
           05  CUST-CARD-EXP-MO    PIC X(2).
           05  CUST-CARD-EXP-YR    PIC X(2).
           05  CUST-CARD-NO        PIC X(19).
           05  FILLER              PIC X(21).
      *
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01 CUST-NO-SRCH               PIC X(6).
       01 FLAGS.
           05 LASTREC                PIC X VALUE 'N'.
              88 LAST-REC                  VALUE 'Y'.
      *------------------
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
      *------------------
       OPEN-FILES.
           ACCEPT CUST-NO-SRCH.
      *
           DISPLAY "SEARCH RECORDS FOR " CUST-NO-SRCH.
      *
        OPEN INPUT  CUST-PROF.
      *
           PERFORM UNTIL LAST-REC
              READ CUST-PROF
                 AT END SET LAST-REC TO TRUE
                 NOT AT END
                 IF CUST-NO-SRCH = CUST-NO
                   DISPLAY "CUSTOMER NAME = "
                    CUST-NAME
                 END-IF
              END-READ
           END-PERFORM.
      *
           CLOSE CUST-PROF.
           STOP RUN.
      *
```

Comment: It's been 20 years since I wrote any COBOL but I saw the error at first glance. Ask yourself why the `OPEN INPUT` statement isn't lined up the same as the other statements and you'll have your answer.

Answer (score 5):

I've edited your question to have code indentation which shows the offending line (which you've seen already):

```
        OPEN INPUT  CUST-PROF.
```

If the indentation doesn't look the same for you the code may contains tabs.

Back to the question:

> why this error code which reads
>
> > "OPEN" should not begin in area "A". It was processed as if found in area "B"

The compiler checks for the ANSI COBOL 85 rule: statements should start in area B:

```
Columns  Field                Description
1-6      Sequence Area        Often empty or line numbers, look out for shop specific rules
7        Indicator            Asterisk (*) = comment line, Hyphen (-) = continuation line,
                              Slash ( / ) = form feed, D = debugging line
8-11     Area A               COBOL definitions: divisions, sections, paragraphs, records and
                              some other entries must *begin* in Area A
12-72    Area B               everything else, including COBOL statements, must begin in area B
73-nn    Identification Area  may contain notes, look out for shop specific rules
```

The compiler says: I do a good guess that this line is meant to be a valid line starting with the `OPEN` statement.